# Расчёт снижения скорости от SSH шифрования

Tags: ssh

Всем привет! Необходимо рассчитать пропускную способность сети при отключенном и включенном SSH шифровании, сеть проводная с протоколом 1000BASE-T. Может кто уже сталкивался с чем то подобным или знает где искать нужную информацию так как гугл ничего полезного не выдаёт.

Comment: На мой взгляд, однозначно посчитать сложно: поскольку всё будет зависеть от опций, скорости CPU, типов и размеров передаваемых данных.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov А если посчитать чисто теоретически? Допустим взять одного юзера с идеальным соединением и пк, который передаёт файл размером скажем 20 гигабайт. Возможно ли просчитать такое?

Comment: Учитывая, что шифрование практически не меняет объема передаваемых данных скорость передачи по сети будет абсолютно той же самой. все задержки происходят исключительно на конечных точках при шифровании/дешифровании. Так что считать надо исключительно скорость шифрования на передающем и дешифровки на принимающем устройстве.

Comment: @Mike Мне кажется можно вычислить на сколько увеличивается объём информации при шифровании.

Comment: Блочные шифры не увеличивают объем, вообще

Comment: А объемом обмена ключами в начале сессии и изредка в середине можно пренебречь

Comment: @Mike Получается что только при установке соединения передаётся ключ а далее данные никак не модифицируются перед отправкой?

Comment: В начале происходит обмен ассиметричными ключами, потом с помощью них шифруется ключ симметричного алгоритма (des, aes, ...) а далее данные уже шифруются этим симметричным ключом, время от времени SSL может решить обновить ключ, но это происходит очень редко, за это время уже пройдут многие мегабайты